# already added: Lcom/android/vending/billing/IMarketBillingService$Stub for android project with maven under intellij?

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

I'm getting error when i'm trying to build android project in intellij 11.1.2

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/android/vending/billing/IMarketBillingService$Stub;`

This project is build on maven pom file. It started to happen after i added dependencie to Android billing library:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeslap</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-billing-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

If i execute `mvn package` in the console it is working fine. Problems only exists for intellij build.

Intellij is adding `IMarketBillingService` in 2 places on classpath as in link below. 
https://skitch.com/ukache/e8ppd/pom.xml-gopro-gopro-projects-labs-mobile-android-gopro

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I found solution => changed intellij compilation to genereate sources and not used maven ones https://img.skitch.com/20120718-qnsan4p8h7c7agyigg31yw1rdf.png

Answer (score 1):

Check if a library (jar file) is not added twice in your Android project

Comment: Are you using any other jars? Sometimes other jars contain the same code.